# drupal_html_id() alternative for non-Ajax content?

Tags: 7, ajax

I am looking for a `drupal_html_id()` function alternative which returns incremented ID's of non-Ajax contents only.

1. Is this "ajax/non-ajax" distinction feasible in this context or any other way?
2. If yes, can anyone provide a solution or recommendation?

Comment: Not sure this makes a lot of sense...perhaps if you explained what problem you're trying solve that would help? Also could you confirm which version you want an answer for? The solution would probably be wildly different between 7 and 8 so you'll need to specify which one answerers should be focusing on. Many thanks

Comment: Actually, to answer the question exactly as it's posed: no, there's no way to do that (just look at the code for `drupal_html_id()` and you'll see why)

Comment: @Clive Thanks, a "no" is a totally adequate answer. To still answer your first question, I am primarily focusing on D8 here. I am setting unique ID's (ex. `#link-key-1--2`, `#link-key-1--3`, etc.) for a set of identical links. These links perform an Ajax request. `drupal_html_id()` then increments the ID in the Ajax response. This is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Ah, that old chestnut :) Usually people want to do this so they can target elements with specific JS and not rely totally on the AJAX API - is that what's happening here?

Comment: Exactly ;) Then, in the JS I will iterate over these elements and perform some actions..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler version I came up with by altering [drupal_html_id()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_html_id/7) that doesn't pay attention to the $ajax_html_ids. Also note that it produces dashes instead of hyphens:

```
function foo_html_id($id) {
  $id = strtr(drupal_strtolower($id), array(' ' => '_', '_' => '_', '[' => '_', ']' => ''));
  $id = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]/', '', $id);
  $id = preg_replace('/\-+/', '_', $id);

  $seen_ids = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

  if (isset($seen_ids[$id])) {
    $id = $id . '_' . ++$seen_ids[$id];
  }
  else {
    $seen_ids[$id] = 1;
  }

  return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manually prevent any handling of AJAX within drupal_html_id():

```
unset($_POST['ajax_html_ids']);
drupal_html_id($some_id);
```

Be careful with this, because any other AJAX-dependent forms rendered after your code will also be affected.